# Initial here tabs are not honoring "optional" flag through the API

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have a template configured that has two required initial here fields. Within my application, I have two InitialHere objects that I am assigning to the collection of initial here tabs.

When I set either of these fields' `optional` flag to `true`, the document that I end up attempting to sign still shows both initial fields as required.

Example of the payload that gets sent along to the API:

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "1",
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "person1+sds@mail.com",
                                "name": "person 1",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "person",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "checkboxTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "selected": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "cb1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "selected": false,
                                            "tabLabel": "cb2"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "initialHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "optional": false,
                                            "tabLabel": "Initial 08a05d74-4b1f-45d5-a070-e67d23032ea5"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "optional": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Initial 7a1662e7-92b5-4d6d-adde-f2099d461bdf"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Line1",
                                            "value": 100000
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Line2",
                                            "value": 2000
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Line3",
                                            "value": 3000
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Line4",
                                            "value": 3000
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Line5",
                                            "value": 200000
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Line6",
                                            "value": 50000
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Line7",
                                            "value": 60000
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Line8",
                                            "value": 60000
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "PrintedName",
                                            "value": "Person 1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "locked": true,
                                            "tabLabel": "Title",
                                            "value": "xxxxxx"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "1"
                }
            ],
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "..."
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

All of the other fields on this template are getting set correctly, such as whether they are locked or not, and the prefilled value. The optional flag of just the initial fields is not working.

Snippet from usage of the php API client library:

```php
    private function buildSectionATabs(): array
    {
        $didNotReduceNumberOfEmployees = (new InitialHere())
            ->setTabLabel("Initial 08a05d74-4b1f-45d5-a070-e67d23032ea5")
            ->setOptional("true");

        $couldNotOperate = (new InitialHere())
            ->setTabLabel("Initial 7a1662e7-92b5-4d6d-adde-f2099d461bdf")
            ->setOptional("true");

        return [$didNotReduceNumberOfEmployees, $couldNotOperate];
    }
```

Then further down just before sending the envelope:

```php
        $initialTabs = array_merge(
            $this->buildSectionATabs()
        );

        return (new Tabs())
            ->setTextTabs($textTabs)
            ->setCheckboxTabs($checkboxTabs)
            ->setInitialHereTabs($initialTabs);
```

As I said earlier, everything else works. Checkboxes show like I expect, and the other set values work, just the optional flag of the InitialHere fields is not working.

Comment: You might want to give out some more information on what you're doing, what code you're trying and what is the expected behavior. Don't think someone will be able to help you without these things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the JSON for the InitialHereTabs:

"tabType":"initialhereoptional"

like this:

```
                               {
                                    "optional": false,
                                    "tabLabel": "Initial 08a05d74-4b1f-45d5-a070-e67d23032ea5"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optional": true,
                                    "tabType" : "initialhereoptional",
                                    "tabLabel": "Initial 7a1662e7-92b5-4d6d-adde-f2099d461bdf"
                                }
```

Comment: Still no go :(. I changed all of the places where I assign a boolean to a string. See question update for what I'm doing.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, let me update. You need to try to add this to the JSON:
"tabType":"initialhereoptional"

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added that setting, and it goes up to the API just as in your example and both initials are still showing as required.